# Can directly passing strings as parameter cause Memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc

In my MFC application when I close it from debug mode in Visual Studio , output window has lines like this-

```
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {415} normal block at 0x028BC410, 21 bytes long. Data: <T  x            > 54 CD FB 78 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 "
```

when I make a breakpoint using allocation number it points to code :

```
if (CMFCToolBar::GetUserImages() == NULL)
{
    if (m_UserImages.Load(_T(".\\UserImages.bmp"))) //call-stack points to this line.
    {
        CMFCToolBar::SetUserImages(&m_UserImages);
    }
}
```

Another sample is as follows:

```
CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
theApp.m_nAppLook = theApp.GetInt(_T("ApplicationLook"), ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_VS_2008);//call-stack points to this line.
}
```

I found all other allocation numbers are leading to lines where strings are directly passed as parameters to a function. My question is : Is this really a memory leak ? If yes then how to avoid this ; maybe initializing a CString variable and pass it as parameter of that function ?

Comment: Can you share code of problematic places?

Comment: it leaks inside Load function?

Comment: Some problamatic code:
1>   theApp.m_nAppLook = theApp.GetInt(_T("ApplicationLook"), ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_VS_2008);

2> m_UserImages.Load(_T(".\\UserImages.bmp"));

@billz : I am not sure if it is memory leak or not. Breakpoint on allocation number points to this codes.

Comment: please update your code in your question :)

Comment: There's no `CWinApp::GetInt` as far as I can tell. Can you perhaps show us the implementation of **that** function? And what does "breakpoint on allocation number" mean?

Comment: @NikBougalis I am referring to this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Codename_DJ that doesn't answer my question - what do you mean by "allocation number"? Do you refer to the address returned from functions that allocate memory? The link you reference provides some information on the Microsoft CRT memory leak detection - a nice tool but hardly authoritative or exhaustive. It will report "leaks" for some things when there might not be any leaks (the reasons are somewhat technical and it's 11:30pm already).

Comment: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {415}

in this line {415} is the allocation number.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/w2fhc9a3(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your title - a string literal does not need to be freed.

As for passing it to a function - it depends on what the function does with it.

For example this function will create a memory leak regardless of what you pass to it:

```
void foo(const char* s) {
    strdup(s); // Memory leak!
}

foo("abc"); // There's a memory leak because foo just created a copy using strdup which it didn't free!
```